# Writing over or below an arrow with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd like to write some text over all the arrows in this diagram. I would like to write some greek letters.
However, when I try to write in the curly brackets it gives me all sorts of errors. What am I missing? Thank you so much!

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[rectangle, draw=black!60, very thick, minimum size=3mm] (v0) at (-6,0) {Search};
\node[rectangle, draw=black!60, very thick, minimum size=3mm] (v1) at (0,0) {Visite al sito};
\node[rectangle, draw=black!60, very thick, minimum size=3mm] (v2) at (-1.5,1.75) {Video};
\node[rectangle, draw=black!60, very thick, minimum size=3mm] (v3) at (2.7,-1.5) {TV GRPs};
\node[rectangle, draw=black!60, very thick, minimum size=3mm] (v4) at (8,0) {Vendite};
\node[rectangle, draw=black!60, very thick, minimum size=3mm] (v5) at (2.7,1.5) {OOH};
\node[rectangle, draw=black!60, very thick, minimum size=3mm] (v6) at (5,-1.5) {SM Paid};
\node[rectangle, draw=black!60, very thick, minimum size=3mm] (v7) at (-3.5,-1.5) {Display};
\node[rectangle, draw=black!60, very thick, minimum size=3mm] (v8) at (-0.5,-1.8) {Utenti App};

%errori
\node   (eps)   at(8,1)   {$\varepsilon_1$}; 
\node   (delta1)    at(-6,1)   {$\delta_1$};
\node   (delta2)    at(0,1)   {$\delta_2$};
\node   (delta3)    at(-1.5,2.75)   {$\delta_3$};
\node   (delta4)    at(2.7,-2.5)   {$\delta_4$};
\node   (delta5)    at(5,-2.5)   {$\delta_5$};
\node   (delta6)    at(2.7,2.5)   {$\delta_6$};
\node   (delta7)    at(-3.5,-2.5)   {$\delta_7$};
\node   (delta8)    at(-0.5,-2.8)   {$\delta_8$};

\draw[->]   (v0) edge (v1)  arc[above] {$a1$};
\draw[->]   (v2) edge (v1)  {};
\draw[->]   (v3) edge (v1)  {};
\draw[->]   (v5) edge (v4)  {};
\draw[->]   (v6) edge (v4)  {};
\draw[->]   (v7) edge (v1)  {};
\draw[->]   (v7) edge (v0)  {};
\draw[->]   (v7) edge (v8)  {};
\draw[->]   (v3) edge (v8)  {};
\draw[->]   (v8) edge (v1)  {};
\draw[->]   (v1) edge (v4)  {};
\draw[->]   (v3) edge (v4)  {};

%errori
\draw[->]   (eps)   edge    (v4)    ;
\draw[->]   (delta1)    edge    (v0);
\draw[->]   (delta2)    edge    (v1);
\draw[->]   (delta3)    edge    (v2);
\draw[->]   (delta4)    edge    (v3);
\draw[->]   (delta5)    edge    (v6);
\draw[->]   (delta6)    edge    (v5);
\draw[->]   (delta7)    edge    (v7);
\draw[->]   (delta8)    edge    (v8);

\label{fig:example}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Example}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Do you mean `\draw[->]   (v0) edge (v1)  node[above] {$a1$};` instead of `\draw[->]   (v0) edge (v1)  arc[above] {$a1$};`?  this `arc` with its optional argument `above` creates problems. Everything else seems to work. Also, the `{}` there means nothing without a node before of them.

Comment: But if I write node[above] then I have a1 written over the node, I want it written over the arrow. How do I achieve that?

Comment: Write it between `edge` and the target, i.e. `edge node[above] {$a1$} (v1)`, or use the `pos` function or its shortcuts, say `edge (v1) node[above,midway]{$a1$}`. With the `quotes` library, you could even do `edge["$a1$" above] (v1)` but that's a whole other thing.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel that was super useful. Thank you so much

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments